# Ensuring a date entered is at least 3 years greater than another

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

I am trying to make a constraint to ensure that the `finishdate` is at least 3 years greater than the `startdate`.

I have had a look around but really do not know where to start?

Would i need to use a `dateadd` function?

Thanks

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `dateadd`. You're probably looking for `add_months`. Since you've tagged it with check-constraints you do seem to know where to start, so have you tried to add a constraint? It might help to show your existing table structure and your best attempt so far, and why it was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it a number of ways, but since you asked about check constraints, something like this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
  id numeric(4),
  startdate date,
  finishdate date,
  CONSTRAINT check_date
  CHECK (finishdate >= add_months( startdate , 36 ))
);
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for that I actually tried something very similar and it just seemed to me the wrong syntax.